# Among the curves whose all tangents pass through the origin, find the one that passes through point $(a,b)$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Among the curves whose all tangents pass through the origin, find the one that passes through point $(a,b)$.

Here is my solution but my answer seems incorrect.

Let $f(x)$ be the function of the curve.
At $(t, f(t))$, the function $y=f(x)$ has a tangent line $y=f'(t)(x-t)+f(t)$.

Since the tangent line passes through the origin, we get

$0=f'(t)(-t)+f(t)$

$tf'(t)=f(t)$,

which can be written as the differential equation $xy'=y$.

After solving the differential equation, I got the family of curve $y = Cx$, which is are composed of straight lines passing through the origin. I am stuck here and don't know what the next step should be.
Please feel free to share your thoughts. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that $y = x + C$ does not pass through the origin unless $C = 0$. Are you sure the differential equation does not yield $y = Cx$ instead?

Comment: "Among the curves whose tangent always passes through the origin, find the one that passes through point $(a,b)$" is difficult for me to understand.  What curves? All of its tangents? Or does it only have one tangent?  You came to the conclusion you are taking about $y=Cx$ (so not curvy at all) and the next step would be to say $C=\frac ba$ so it passes through $(a,b)$

Comment: @Henry. Thank you for trying to understand the question. Based on my professor, among the curves whose all tangents pass through the origin, I was asked to find the one that passes through point $(2,4)$. But I would like to know what the general equation of will be the any of that curve using the arbitrary point $(a,b)$

Comment: @DarthGeek, Thanks for your feedback. I stand corrected. I edited my text based on your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now just substitute $x=a,y=b$ into $y=Cx$ and get $C=\frac ba$. If $(a,b)$ is not the origin itself, $y=\frac bax$ is unique.

Comment: Thank you. I think my problem is that I assume that the curve should be a curve line that is why I am hesitant with my answer. So, a line could be considered as a curve.

Comment: @PRD All lines are curves, really.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. A line can be thought of as a special case of a curve with zero curvature.

Comment: @PRD Please accept my answer if you found it useful.